# What is the difference between @UiThread and @MainThread annotation in Android?

Tags: android, annotations

I thought the [@UiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/UiThread.html) and [@MainThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/MainThread.html) were the same thing.

Comment: I didn't understand what is @MainThread annotation and what are its usage. Can you please explain it. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between the main thread and UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784584/difference-between-the-main-thread-and-ui-thread)

Comment: how does the annotation "checks"? throws an exception? `Thread annotations check if a method is called from`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**@MainThread** is the first thread that starts running when you start your application

**@UiThread** starts from Main Thread for Rendering user Interface

Also from Android Documentation

Note: The @MainThread and the @UiThread annotations are interchangeable so methods calls from either thread type are allowed for these annotations.

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html#thread-annotations

Comment: It's the same thread. They just name it UI thread because that is where the rendering of the UI happens and the implementation might change in the future.

Comment: That's not 100% correct, it's not just different naming, as the documentation says: 
> **Note:** Ordinarily, an app's UI thread is also the main thread. However, under special circumstances, an app's UI thread might not be its main thread; for more information, see [Thread annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#thread-annotations) < Although I have to admit I don't know what those special circumstances are :D

Comment: how does the annotation "checks"? throws an exception? `Thread annotations check if a method is called from`

Answer (score 3):

More complete explanation:  It's possible for a UI thread to be different from the main thread in the case of system apps with multiple views on different threads. Therefore, you should annotate methods associated with an app's **view hierarchy** with `@UiThread` and annotate only methods associated with an app's **lifecycle** with `@MainThread`.